# Access - Use date if available, else use today's date

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

So this is driving me crazy and it should be super easy to do. I don't know why I can't get it working. :( At present my functions are calculating the difference between a start date and today's date, and it's working great, but now I need to implement an optional end date. So if there is an EmpEndDate available, it should be used, otherwise today's date should be used.

Here's one of my functions:

```
Public Function RetentionMonths(ByVal EmpStartDate As Date) As Integer

    Dim RetentionStartdate As Date
    Dim FollowingMonth As Date

        RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(EmpStartDate), EmpStartDate))
        FollowingMonth = DateSerial(Year(RetentionStartdate), Month(RetentionStartdate) + 1, 1)
        RetentionMonths = Months(FollowingMonth, Date)

End Function
```

Edit: The Months() function

```
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)

  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```

And one way I've tried to tackle the issue:

```
Public Function RetentionMonths(ByVal EmpStartDate As Date, _
    Optional ByVal EmpEndDate As Date) _
    As Integer

    Dim RetentionStartdate As Date
    Dim FollowingMonth As Date

        RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(EmpStartDate), EmpStartDate))
        FollowingMonth = DateSerial(Year(RetentionStartdate), Month(RetentionStartdate) + 1, 1)
        RetentionMonths = Months(FollowingMonth, Nz(EmpEndDate, Date))

End Function
```

I'm either getting crazy negative numbers in fields that used to work, or #Name? errors.

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks'? What error do you get? EmpEndDate is not referenced in any expression. Perhaps you need to use Nz() function. You have a custom function Months()? The intrinsic function is Month().

Comment: I do not see you declare EmpEndDate  anywhere in the code you provide so where would this variable come from?

Comment: @Sorceri it's not referenced anywhere in the function either. Perhaps OP means to add it as a parameter?

Comment: My sincerest apologies for not providing nearly enough information. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for the value of 0 for the end date by using clng

```
Public Function RetentionMonths(ByVal EmpStartDate As Date, _
    Optional ByVal EmpEndDate As Date) _
    As Integer

    Dim RetentionStartdate As Date
    Dim FollowingMonth As Date
    Dim tempEndDate As Date

    If CLng(EmpEndDate) = 0 Then EmpEndDate = Now()


        RetentionStartdate = DateAdd("ww", 14, DateAdd("d", vbSaturday - Weekday(EmpStartDate), EmpStartDate))
        FollowingMonth = DateSerial(Year(RetentionStartdate), Month(RetentionStartdate) + 1, 1)
        RetentionMonths = Months(FollowingMonth, Nz(EmpEndDate, Date))

End Function
```

Comment: It works! It's a miracle! But only when there's an EmpStartDate entered. Otherwise, I get #Type! errors. Why is this?

Comment: @Zuzu You have a Nz function that I do not know.  I ran this giving a start date of 45 days previous to today and an end date of now.  Removing the Nz Function it returns -2 so possible your error is in there?...

Comment: You don't have to convert to a number. Dates are dates, so: `If EmpEndDate = #00:00# Then EmpEndDate = Date`.

Comment: Hrm. I'm clearly not understanding. I've tried the following (and a few slight variations) in VBA: ?RetentionMonths(2015-01-01, Nz(EmpEndDate, Date)) and ?RetentionMonths(2015-01-01, Nz(2017-06-29, Date)) ... And I'm getting 1339 or -4. Ack. I'm sorry, I'm such a noob. :( I also clearly don't know how to format comments here either... sorry for the block of text.

Comment: @Zuzu  add the NZ function to your question

Comment: Sorceri, would it be possible for you to provide an example? Terribly sorry for the trouble!

Comment: in your RetentionMonths function the last line is RetentionMonths = Months(FollowingMonth, Nz(EmpEndDate, Date)).  NZ(Date, Date) is a Method you must have created.  Edit your question to include this method.  Also an example of how you are calling the method and I am guessing the cell format as well.

Comment: Forgot to follow up on this question -- oops. I rewrote the whole thing from scratch and got it working. Must've been some stupid little typo somewhere. Thank you for your help!! :)